# CURL Error in Encoding the Characters

Tags: php, dom, curl, character-encoding

I am trying to Fetch Some data from a Web Page. But the issue is instead of Pulling say :

```
64 × 191 × 75 cm
```

it displays on echo as

```
64 Ã— 191 Ã— 75 cm
```

My code:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.google.co.uk"
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;      +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");

$html = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$q_Dimensions = "//tr/td[@class='FieldTitle'][contains(.,'Dimensions of packed product (W×H×D):')]/following-sibling::td/text()";
$dimentionsQ = $xpath->query($q_Dimensions);
$dimentions = $dimentionsQ->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $dimentions;
exit();
```

I believe this could be some sort of issue with the Character Encoding but not able to go any further. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, setting the `charset` to `UTF-8` in `header()` works fine also:

```
// add this on the top of your php script
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$url = "google.co.uk";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;      +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");

$html = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$q_Dimensions = "//tr/td[@class='FieldTitle'][contains(.,'Dimensions of packed product (W×H×D):')]/following-sibling::td/text()";
$dimentionsQ = $xpath->query($q_Dimensions);
$dimentions = $dimentionsQ->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $dimentions; // 64 × 191 × 75 cm
exit();
```

Comment: Works Perfectly fine... thanks for the Help and Effort @Ghost much appreciated. Saved alot of time

Answer (score 1):

set another curl option for  CURLOPT_ENCODING and set it to "" to ensure it will not return any garbage

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
```

Comment: Hi @Anri thanks for the Reply but as you can see in the Code Above I have already added that option in Line 8. but still gives the same issue.

Comment: This is so useful! upvote x100!